# slick grid skip columns when tabbing

Tags: slickgrid

Is there a way that i can prevent a user from tabbing through a specific column when using slick grid?

I would like the tab to jump a readonly column where the other ones on either side have editors.

Answer (score 5):

Use the property 'focusable' in the column's options. The [documentation](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki/Column-Options) says:

> When set to false, clicking on a cell in this column will not select the row for that cell. The cells in this column will also be skipped during tab navigation.

The columns definition will look like that:

```
var columns = [
  { id: "EditableCulumn", name: "Editable", field: "Name", editor: Slick.Editors.Text }
, { id: "ReadOnlyColumn", name: "ReadOnly", field: "ID", focusable: false }
]
```